# Create fluidRows in a loop R Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

Hello everyone ‍♂️

I’m having an issue with creating inputs in a shiny app. 
I would like to create a few fluidRows, all of which are very similar and only differ by input id and initial value.

I tried a for loop, however the rows don’t build at all. Here’s an example of what I tried:

Init_vals <- c(1,2,3,4,5)

```
#Within fluidPage:

for( i in 1:5){
  fluidRow(
     textInput( inputId=paste0(“id”,i) ,
                      label = “”,
                      value = Init_vals[i]
                    )
}
```

Surely there’s a way to create multiple fluidRows without having to do it manually? I think I must be missing something and any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Cheers

Comment: You will need to generate the inputs on the server side (`renderUI`) and visualize them in the UI part using `uiOutput`. See [here](http://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/renderUI.html) for more info.

Answer (score 1):

I do not believe you can use a loop within the UI part of the app. I have approached similar situations using `uiOutput` and `renderUI` to accomplish this:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  uiOutput("ui1")
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  Init_vals <- 1:5

  output$ui1 <- renderUI({

    ui_parts <- c()

    for(i in 1:5){
      ui_parts[[i]] <- fluidRow(
        textInput(
          inputId=paste0("id",i) ,
          label = "here",
          value = Init_vals[i]
        )
      )
    }

    ui_parts

  })

}


shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

All the ui elements are is some text (test this by saving a shiny-generated UI element to a variable and priniting in your console), so you can generate them however you want using `renderUI`, here saving them to a list in a loop.

Answer (score 0):

I already worked on this some times ago. The best solution I found was to define a function (say something like `multipleRows()`) with a `n` argument equal to the number of rows you want. Also, you could add a `content` argument to fill your `fluidRow`s.

But what did all the magic when I tried this was the **`do.call()`** function. It allows to call the `renderUI()` function with the desired argument input in a *list* object.

Voluntarily, I do not give a full written answer as I find this is an interesting execise to understand UI-server relationship within Shiny.

Comment: Cheers you two, both solutions worked and I’m so happy to not have to manually write 100’s of inputs!